# pass nested callbacks as argument javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a block of code like that

```
function doA (callback) {
    //do something...
    callback();
}

function doB (callback) {
    //do something...
    callback();
}

function doC () {
    //do something...
}
```

i know it's a bad practice and have to avoid it, but i am trying to understand why when i called the functions as

```
doA(doB(doC)));
```

it throwed an error that "callback is not a function" ?
But when i tried:

```
doA(doC);
```

everything was ok.

edited: i have tried to use chrome dev tool to figure out how javascript callstack works here, and i found out that the call stack be like:

```
doC
doB
```

there isn't doA function, so why js avoids adding doA() to the callstack?

Comment: @YounisArM — No. It shouldn't.

Comment: "why js avoids adding doA() to the callstack?" — It doesn't. You must be looking at it at the wrong time. http://i.imgur.com/NDsY9RN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it throwed an error that "callback is not a function" ?

You call `doA` and pass the return value of `doB(doC)` as the first argument.

`doB` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

`doA` tries to call the first argument (which has the value `undefined`) as a function, which it isn't, so it fails.

---

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to achieve (since your example code has been abstracted so much), but you should probably investigate [the Promises API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which would let you do something like:

```
doA().then(doB).then(doC);
```

Answer (score 0):

because `doB` it's not returning a function.

that expression means that the output of `doB` is passed as argument to `doA`,  but since `doB` is not returning a function you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing result of `doB(doC)` as the argument of `doA` but it is not a function:

```
doB(doC); // undefined
doA(undefined); // throws: callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

For callback you need to pass function and doB(doC) will execute it and will return undefined. And that undefined value will get passed to doA(undefined) and thats why you are getting -
callback is not a function